# How can I make my wireless work?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I just changed my OS from windows to ubuntu 16.10 and the problem is since then my wireless doesn't work at all, I can't see any WİFİ conection so I have to plug the ethernet cable to get connection.I don't know where is the problem since it was working well in windows. But I checked the network hardware by this comand `lshw -C network` and here is the output

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: enp8s0
   version: 07
   serial: ec:b1:d7:bc:19:6f
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.26 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:41 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:b5600000-b5600fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
*-generic
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Illegal Vendor ID
   vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: ff
   serial: 74:29:af:0c:bf:a5
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.8.0-41-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b5500000-b5503fff
```

could someone help me with this please??I don't know if it's important to notice but in case it is I am using a HP-15-NOTEBOOK....since I am a new user in ubuntu please make the explanations as clear as you can...Thank you

Comment: please edit with more info, like screenshots, error messages, etc.

Comment: how can I check my drivers?? what is the comand??

Comment: oh nvm, you did it...

Comment: hmm, it says here on the generic side, `illegal vendor id,` there's clearly a problem on the wireless interface. @kalbert

Comment: oh wait you dont have windows xD

Comment: how can I fix it please?? I really need it.

Comment: I would power it down and remove the wireless card and reinstall

Comment: could you explain clearly how to do that??@Jeremy31

Comment: Do a google search for you laptop model and wireless card, you will likely find instructions or a video

Comment: i doubt that will work- give ^ a try, tsk tsk compatability. or just stick with plain wires

Comment: the rtl8723be driver it's for ethernet interface....as displayed in my code above it seems like the wireless interface doesn't show any driver since it says illegal vendor ID.....can someone help me with this?

Comment: Hopefully you've upgraded to a supported version by now and a newer kernel has resolved your issue.  If you've moved to a supported version and still have this issue please review [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and [edit] a link to a [pastie](https://pastebin.com/) of the output into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Please upgrade to 17.04 and try. Newer versions ship with newer updates, the problem may be fixed. If it isn't, please give us your exact model number. HP Notebook 15 is a very broad model, there are many sub-models.

Answer (score 1):

Did a net search - rtl8723be and ubuntu? Discovered that there are problems with setting up this Realtek wireless device. Some info was available about configuring this device that will be helpful to you. One caveat here - Follow instructions and enter commands Carefully! There seem to be some modprobe commands. This command works with kernel modules and are not to be used without healthy respect. You will have to connect to the net with either another PC or use the wired ethernet connection to get the information and any downloads that may be required. This search could be done on the Ask Ubuntu page as well.

Comment: the rtl8723be driver it's for ethernet interface....as displayed in my code above it seems like the wireless interface doesn't show any driver since it says illegal vendor ID.....can someone help me with this?

Comment: can you share the link??

Comment: Did not actually view a page,  Links will be found by doing the same search - 'rtl8723be and ubuntu?'

Answer (score 0):

Just go to additional driver ...put the LAN cable(internet cable) it will automatically search for the driver and just install it by selecting apply ...you will be able to use wireless internet in just few seconds... Go for it

Comment: that didn't work.@Ajaz